# Use PL/pgSQL in PostgreSQL outside of a stored procedure or function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'd really like to use an `IF`, `ELSE` construct and execute multiple statements within the `IF` and `ELSE` blocks, but I don't wish to save my commands to the database as a stored procedure or function. Can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [**`DO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command for ad-hoc plpgsql execution.
But you cannot pass parameters or return rows directly to / from a `DO` command.

BTW, strictly speaking, Postgres does not have "stored procedures" before Postgres 11. Just functions providing very similar functionality. See:

- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a "Stored Procedure" and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/in-postgresql-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-other-typ)

Comment: Your response was very informative. Thanks for the extra caveat.