# How to return values from psql to bash with custom session settings

Tags: postgresql, transaction, psql, bash, sql-procedure

I need to set the `datestyle` to `"dd/mm/yyyy"` before calling a procedure and getting it's return value back to bash.
I tried the following:

```sh
read return <<< $(psql \
                  -x \
                  -U postgres \
                  -d MY_DB \
                  --quiet`\
                  -t \
                  -c "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")    //just to make sure the date format is correct 
echo ${return[0]} | cut -d'|' -f 2
```

I'm getting back a normal date format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Why can't you just use  `-c "set datestyle = 'sql, dmy';select current_timestamp;"` argument?

Comment: @peremeykin: That might not work with a *procedure*.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if the output format matters, rather use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) instead of depending on the [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting. Like:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

But to answer your question:

> I need to set the `datestyle` to `"dd/mm/yyyy"`

`"dd/mm/yyyy"` isn't a valid setting, this would do it:

```
datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'
```

The `datestyle` setting is a bit odd for historical reasons. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT)

> In the `SQL` and `POSTGRES` styles, day appears before month if `DMY` field ordering has been specified, otherwise month appears before day.

Also, I suggest multiple, separate `-c` options for psql:

```sh
postgres@test:~$ read return <<< $(psql \
>                   -x \
>                   -U postgres \
>                   -d MY_DB \
>                   --quiet \
>                   -t \
>                   -c "SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'" \
>                   -c 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
postgres@test:~$ echo ${return[0]} | cut -d'|' -f 2
 08/11/2021 22:37:11.915721 CET
```

You mentioned:

> before calling a procedure

Unless you actually mean *"function"* and just use the wrong term (a widespread misnomer), a single `-c` option, as has been suggested, does not work if the `PROCEDURE` uses any transaction control commands (`COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK`, ...). And those are the main reason to use a procedure rather than a function in the first place. See:

- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a "Stored Procedure" and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/in-postgresql-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-other-typ/194811#194811)

[The manual on *Transaction Management*:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

> Transaction control is only possible in `CALL` or `DO` invocations
> from the top level or nested `CALL` or `DO` invocations without any
> other intervening command.

[The manual for psql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3)

> Each SQL command string passed to `-c` is sent to the server as a
> single request. Because of this, the server executes it as a single
> transaction even if the string contains multiple SQL commands, unless
> there are explicit `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands included in the string to
> divide it into multiple transactions. (See Section [53.2.2.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-MULTI-STATEMENT) for
> more details about how the server handles multi-query strings.) Also,
> `psql` only prints the result of the last SQL command in the string.
> This is different from the behavior when the same string is read from
> a file or fed to psql's standard input, because then psql sends each
> SQL command separately.
>
> Because of this behavior, putting more than one SQL command in a
> single `-c` string often has unexpected results. **It's better to use
> repeated `-c` commands** or feed multiple commands to psql's standard
> input, either using echo as illustrated above, or via a shell
> here-document ...

Bold emphasis mine.

So while this works:

```
 -c "SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'; SELECT current_timestamp;"
```

This doesn't (if the procedure uses transaction control commands):

```
 -c "SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'; CALL my_procedure();"
```

You'd get this  error:

> ERROR:  invalid transaction termination

Comment: Thanks for the extensive repy, what I'm trying to do is exactly this, set datestyle to `SQL,DMY` sorry if it isn't in the question, and then call a procedure -that **has** transacion controls- but for some reason needs to check if the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` because **client!!** or else it stops execution, so yeah, i'm trying `-c "SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'; CALL my_procedure();"` and it' not failing, but i'm still not geting the dateformat that i want, somehow either it's getting ignored, or it's being reset, thank you

Comment: If the procedure has transaction control commands, this call should certainly fail: `-c "SET datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'; CALL my_procedure();"` It fails for me, testing with current Postgres 14.

Comment: @Majd: So is this question answered properly?